I'm creating a new trait but values are initialized to null
I have a trait that looks like this
private[name] trait HttpIssuer extends HttpIssuerImpl with JsonApi with Logging {
  def credentials: ApiCredentials
  def maxAllowedQuota: Int
  def minHour: Option[Int]
  def maxHour: Option[Int]
  implicit def session: Session


  val throttling = new Throttling(maxPerSecond = 5, maxPerMinute = 300)
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
  val hasTimeRange = minHour.isDefined || maxHour.isDefined
  var response: Option[MarketoIdentityResponse] = None
  var authorization: Option[String] = response.map(_.accessToken)

  var previouslyUsedApiQuota: Int = 0
  var numberOfQueries: Int = 0

override def executeRequest(request: RestRequest): ApiResponse = {
  executeRequest(request, 0)
}

def executeRequest(request: RestRequest, retries: Int = 0): ApiResponse = {
   if (numberOfQueries + previouslyUsedApiQuota > maxAllowedQuota) {
     warn("Exceeded max allowed API quota of " + maxAllowedQuota +
        " based on previously used quota of " + previouslyUsedApiQuota + " and new API usage of " + numberOfQueries)
      System.exit(0)
     }
   }
}

I'm trying to test the executeRequest method, to make sure it fails when numberOfQueries + previouslyUsedApiQuota > maxAllowedQuota, numberOfQueries = 0 and previouslyUsedApiQuota = 0 so if maxAllowedQuota = -1 it should fail, my test is below
@Test
  def test_executeRequestExits: Unit = {
    val creds = ApiCredentials (
      instanceId = "dummy-instance-id",
      clientId = "dummy-client-id",
      clientSecret = "String",
      soapUserId = "String",
      encryptionKey = "String"
    )

    val mockRequest = mock(classOf[RestRequest])
    val issuer = new HttpIssuer {
      override val credentials: ApiCredentials = creds
     override implicit val session: Session = new Session {
        override def isInTransaction: Boolean = false
        override def tenant: String = "test-tenant"
        override def jdbcSession(): JdbcSession = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented for testing")
      }
      // give negative quota so I enter error handling
      override val maxAllowedQuota: Int = -1
      override val minHour: Option[Int] = Some(1)
      override val maxHour: Option[Int] = Some(2)
    }

    val mockApiFailure = mock(classOf[ApiFailure])
    when(mockApiFailure.code).thenReturn("601") // Access token expired

    when(MarketoHttpIssuer.failureGauge(any())(any())).thenReturn(any())

    val executeRequestReturn = issuer.executeRequest(mockRequest)
    class NoExitSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
      var exitCalled = false
      var exitStatus: Option[Int] = None

      override def checkExit(status: Int): Unit = {
        exitCalled = true
        exitStatus = Some(status)
      }
    }

    val securityManager = new NoExitSecurityManager
    // Verify that System.exit was called with 0
    assert(securityManager.exitCalled)
    assert(securityManager.exitStatus.contains(0))

    // Restore the original security manager
    System.setSecurityManager(null)
  }

The problem I'm having is that when I initialize the trait I get a null pointer exception. I stepped through the code and the problem seems to be on this line
val hasTimeRange = minHour.isDefined || maxHour.isDefined
But in the trait I set them both to Some(1) so I am not sure why the trait is setting them to null? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?
Also, when I put a break point in this line
val issuer = new MarketoHttpIssuer, it seems to hover into it more than once, maybe I'm misunderstanding how to properly initialize a trait?

Does this answer your question? How does the initialization of classes in Scala work?

Short answer: don't use vals in traits unless you know what you're doing (this is overly simplified but I think it's a good thing to remember when writing a trait).
